# Greedy regex behavior not wanted. usual cures don't work

Tags: regex, awk

I have a large document that I needed to put anchors in. I appended a number to the end of the line. The format was " Area 1"  This list goes on for hundreds of entries.

I tried to awk out the slice I wanted with the anchor but this is what I get.

```
cat file | awk '/Area 5/{print $0}'
Area 5
Area 50
Area 51
Area 52
Area 53
Area 54
Area 55
Area 56
Area 57
Area 58
Area 59
```

As you can see I wanted just "Area 5" but the regex engine matched it with 5 and 5x. Yes, I know it is being greedy. I tried to limit that behavior with:

```
/Area 5{1}/
```

and I still had this problem. I also tried {0} and {0,1} to no effect.

Question 1: What can I do to force awk (and grep as well) to limit it to the requested number?

Question 2: I  used `awk '/pattern/ { $0=$0 "" ++i }1'` to append the number. It leaves "Area 1"  I would like it to be Area1. Any ideas?

Thanks for the help.
B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid matching prefixes like '5x', you can use a word boundary.
([Explanation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html))

In awk, word boundaries are matched using `\y`.
To eliminate the space between area I simply match group 'Area' and the number '5' and then print them without space.

In my tests, the following worked:

```
 cat test.txt | awk '/Area 5\y/{print $1 $2}'
```

Output

```
Area5
```

Comment: Lot of good answers. Thank you. It works great. I have a second follow up question. The number is the anchor so I need to interate through it to get all the values. I'm trying this on the CL.>     for i in {1..96}; do awk -v n="$i" '/Area n\y/{print $1, $2 $3}'; done

Comment: I have never been able to mix and match variables with strings. How might I do it?

Answer (score 2):

`/Area 5([^0-9]|$)/` would account for end of line, as well as any-thing but a digit.

But a more `awk` way of doing things, would be:

```
awk '/^Area/ && $2==5' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If the '5' is the end of the line, you can use `/Area 5$/`.  The $ matches end-of-line.

If it's followed by further text, `/Area 5[^0-9]/` should work.  The `[^0-9]` matches one character that is anything except a digit.

Good luck!

Comment: And if I understand your second question, you want to eliminate the extra space between your second slash and your opening curly brace.

Comment: i find this regex to be more readable. The super-secret regex stuff just gives me headaches. I don't understand it and I think I will only be able to do so if I become a regex ninja.  Thank you.

Comment: You bet!  A little new stuff at a time.  The notion I think you were missing with regular expressions is that they say nothing about what comes after them, which is why you were matching 50 etc. when you didn't want to.  That's why REs have syntax for 'not characters' like end-of-line and word boundary.

Comment: good point. I'm still learning them. can you see my comment above about mixing strings and variables while searching for text?  for i in {1..96}; do awk -v n="$i" '/Area n\y/{print $1, $2 $3}'; done   How do I make that work?

Answer (score 0):

Some proposals.
awk '$2==5' file 
Area 5

awk '$2 ~ /^[5]$/' file
Area 5